# 401 Unauthorized response for access_token in the developer sandbox

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using developer sandbox to make all my api calls.
It's website build with laravel 5.2
All api calls are made with [guzzle/guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle).

I'm trying automate sending pdf contracts (creating envelopes) using docusign api.

I followed steps from [Using the Authorization Code Grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html)

I had no problem with:

1. [Starting the Authentication Code Grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html#starting-the-authentication-code-grant)
2. [Handling the Response](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html#handling-the-response)
3. [Exchanging the Code for a Token](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html#exchanging-the-code-for-a-token)
4. [Getting the User’s Account and Base URI Information](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html#getting-the-users-account-and-base-uri-information)

After I get [userinfo](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/userinfo.html), there is only one account, so I used that accounts **base_uri** for all subsequent api calls
`{base_uri} + "/restapi/v2/accounts/" + {account_id}`

In all my subsequent api calls I'm also adding header

`Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eX...MrhIddzBAQ`

where I'm using **access_token** that I've got in step **Exchanging the Code for a Token**

When doing a [create envelope api call](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/), or any other api call, using **access_token**, **base_uri** and **account_id** I get
`POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<account_id>/envelopes` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response

**What I tried**

Test using the **access_token** in docusign API explorer:
I went to [API EXPLORER - create envelope](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Envelopes&tags=Envelopes&operations=create)
I used **Authenticate using Sandbox Account** to authenticate with the **access_token** that I've got in previous calls to docusign. Same for the **account_id**.

When I click on **SEND REQUEST**, I get **401 Unauthorized** response again.

When I use **Authenticate using Sandbox Account**, but this time I click on **Get OAuth2 token** (that generates new token), and I click on **SEND REQUEST**, I get success message.

Then I copied this **access_token** (from **Request**) into my website to test the api call, and this time it worked. It also worked for all other api calls that I was making to docusign.

- So, using **access_token** that I get after **Exchanging the Code for a Token**, I get **401 Unauthorized** for api calls
- When I use **access_token** that I generated in **API explorer**, all api calls to docusign work in my website.

**What I also tried**

- Use **refresh_token** to get new **access_token**. Still **401**
- Xdebug, going step by step to make sure that all params/headers are set before api call. They are, and they are the same as api explorer.
- Guzzle option `debug => true` to get more information about the request, and to compare with what's sent in **API EXPLORER**, and they are basically the same, except the tokens.
- Postman to make request to api, (just to eliminate any chance that I have errors in my code), with same behavior:

  - 401 with token that I get from docusign
  - success when using **API EXPLORER** generated token

I'm kinda lost on what to do next and how to solve this, I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't seem to locate the problem.

## Update

I used Larry K's answer and found that my problem was with the scope value in /oauth/auth call. I changed it to `scope=signature%20extended`, and everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click the **Get OAuth2 token** in the API explorer, you are going through the complete Authorization Code Grant flow, including the new token.

Since this works, but the token your app obtained via the OAuth Authorization Code flow doesn't work, this tells me that your app has an issue.

Check:

1. Logout from DocuSign. Login from your app. Are you transferred to DocuSign to log in correctly? And then redirected to your app?
2. Are you requesting the "**signature**" scope in your request? Check spelling and capitalization of the scope name!
3. When you're redirected to your app, your app receives the authorization code as a query parameter. Do you get it ok?
4. When you convert your authorization code to a bearer token are you storing the complete bearer token? It is quite long.
5. When you send your Envelopes::create request, are you including a space between the word Bearer and the token itself?
6. Are you making your API call to `demo.docusign.net` (not .com)

If the above doesn't help, then please update your question (you can edit your question itself) with a trace of your request.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this, I'll update my question soon, just to check all the things that you mentioned

Comment: It was problem with the scope value in `/oauth/auth` call, at one point I changed from **signature** to **extended** while testing refresh token... And skipped reading 'allow permissions page'... I changed it to **scope=signature%20extended**, and everything works perfectly! Thank you so much, I wish I could accept your answer multiple times :)

Comment: Should I update question with this information? (my first question on SO...)

Comment: Hi @ljubadr -- glad to help! Since my answer got you in the right direction, you should not put in another answer of your own. Only do that if no one gave you any useful answers. You could update your question by adding to the bottom of it, I will edit your question as an example of what to do. 

Thank you for using StackOverflow and for checking my answer. And thank you for using DocuSign.

Comment: Thank you once again for taking your time to look into this! I didn't want to create a new answer, but I just wasn't sure if I should update the question. Thank you for updating that as well! Docusign has great support :) Have a nice day!

Comment: In my case, I didn't realize the names of the Scopes were different for different APIs. This page has most of them in one place: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/scopes/